# Can not Find Elements on the production Server, Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, drop-down-menu, react-dom

this question might seem dumb but I am facing a problem regarding finding of elements in Facebook. The issue is I want to change the language of the user so I go to the tab to change language and there is a drop-down(dynamic as I read on internet) and you can change language but when you click on the drop-down and enter the class name (or id or xpath or selectors) it does not show that any element is present there, but when I inspect those elements , the code renders and then I can find the elements in the Dev Tools using the same class(id or xpath or selectors).

When I run the code in my local machine(uses remote browser), the bot goes to drop-down, clicks on it and executes the line to find the options of the drop-down, and it successfully finds the 114 options and clicks on the desired one but the main problem occurs when I want to use the same code on a production server (Scaleaway server and also remote browser), the length of the list of the elements find out to be zero and hence the code breaks.

***URL to change Language of the account: https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=language***

[image]

Details for Image : These are the HTML tags and code related to this drop down, only appears when I specifically inspect the element and box, but when I close the drop down and enter the same id or selector I inspected , I get no elements related to it , Selenium somehow does find through my local machine but fails with the server side code

```
languages = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//span[contains(@class,"d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql lr9zc1uh 
            a8c37x1j fe6kdd0r mau55g9w c8b282yb keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em 
            iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v ekzkrbhg oo9gr5id hzawbc8m")]')
sleep(2)
print(f" Languages found: {len(languages)}")
```

I get length of the list as 114 through my local machine but 0 with server.

Can any one figure this out and how can I use Selenium to solve this issue ?

Comment: I don't really find any element within the snapshot with classnames _`d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql lr9zc1uh 
            a8c37x1j fe6kdd0r mau55g9w c8b282yb keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em 
            iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v ekzkrbhg oo9gr5id hzawbc8m`_, Am I missing something?

Comment: thats the thing , you need to first click drop down menu , then you will need to inspect the elements inside the menu , and then only you will see the elements with this class name.